# function prevents rest of code from working

Tags: javascript

```
function updateScreen() {
  var textOutput = "";
  setScreen("yellowScreen");
  for (var i=0; i < finalColor.length; i++){
    var newIndex = i+1;
    textOutput = (((textOutput + newIndex +". NAME: " +finalName[i] + ", " 
+ "scientific name is") + finalScientificName[i] + ", " + "this bird is 
")+ finalConservationStatues[i] + "and they eat ")+ finalDiet[i]+"\n\n";
  }
  setText("yellowOutput", textOutput);
  console.log(textOutput);
}

onEvent("yellowButton", "click", function( ) {
 yellowFilter();
 upDateScreen();
});
```

the function yellowFilter  prevents anything else to run

```
function yellowFilter() {


for (var i = 0; color.length; i++) {
if (color[i] == 'Yellow' ) {
  appendItem(finalColor, color[i]);
  appendItem(finalDiet, diet[i]);
  appendItem(finalConservationStatues, conservationStatus[i]);
  appendItem(finalScientificName, scientificName[i]);
  appendItem(finalName, Name[i]);
  console.log(finalColor);
   }
  }
 }
```

is there anything wrong with these functions  the update screen function doesn't run if the yellowFilter runs but yellowFilter needs to run so that upDateScreen can run properly

Comment: JS is a case-sensitive language. It should be "updateScreen()" after yellowFilter instead of upDateScreen()"

Comment: so after correcting my mistake nothing changed and the code didn't run (I am on code.org if that could be a reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually going through anything I see one error immediately:
for (var i = 0; ***color.length***; i++)

The second statement in a for loop needs to be a conditional

Comment: bless your soul.

Comment: This is definitely the error, and I'll add that `color.length` alone as a `for` condition means "as long as `color.length` is nonzero". Since `color` does not change and its `length` is always nonzero, the loop will run forever. Certainly the OP wanted `i < color.length`